# Express static won't load CSS files from root

Tags: css, node.js, express, static, ejs

My app is loaded from a url such as : `server.com/pdf/12345`. When it is looking for the static files, it tries to `GET /pdf/12345/assets/css/stylesheet.css` and 404s. I can't figure out how to tell it to look for `/public/assets` in the root. Tried a number of different `express.static` configurations.

my directory structure looks like this:

```
public
--assets
----css
views
--partials
----header.ejs
routes
--api.js
server.js
```

server.js looks like this (minus the requires for clarity):

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
http.createServer(app).listen(port, function() {
})
```

My partials/header.ejs contains link to stylesheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write it like this instead:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

If you start with `app.use('/public'` you are telling express to only mount the function on the path `/public`, in your case i guess if the url starts with `server.com/public`. But since that is not the case, `express.static()` never fires.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately its still appending the /pdf/1234/ path when trying to retrieve the assets: `GET /pdf/1234/assets/css/style.css 404`

Comment: Ok. And in your ejs-file you write the href as "/assets/css/stylesheet.css"? If so, then I don't know what you've done wrong.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I was missing the leading slash in the href in the EJS file.

Comment: Full endpoint example? What's path? If I want `localhost:3456/index` to serve `index.html` that contains a link to `index.css` in its head element, what should be done?